# Ter dois dbContext para uma mesma connection string é considerado uma má prática?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tinha inicialmente um `DbContext` com todos os `DbSets` de minhas entidades. Contudo, precisei criar um `DbContext<T>` que possui um `DbSet` genérico para métodos que são propriamente genéricos. Acontece que os dois DbContext apontam para a mesma connectionstring. A existência de ambos em um projeto pode ser considerado uma má prática? Caso sim, qual seria a maneira mais viável de realizar operações genéricas com um `database context` não genérico?

Comment: Mostre a DbContext genérica e a que não é. Essa informação pode ser a resposta a sua pergunta. Ter dois DbContext não é má prática, mas, a repetição de código é, por isso mostrar seu código pode nos conduzir uma melhor resposta!

Comment: O que você quer dizer com *realizar operações genéricas*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ter apenas um *DbContext* pode ser uma má prática se as entidades que contém não tiverem relação entre elas.

Seguindo a abordagem **DDD** - *Domain-driven design*, quando estamos perante muitas entidades, estas devem ser agrupadas de acordo com o contexto em que se relacionam.

Por exemplo, se a sua aplicação tiver que tratar a área de stocks e de pessoal de uma empresa deverão ser definidos dois *DbContext*, um para as entidades de **Stocks** outro paras as entidades de **Pessoal**.

Veja [aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) o que é DDD.

Em relação à sua pergunta em concreto não vejo qual é a necessidade de ter dois *DbContext*.

Nota: Ter mais que um *DbContext* para uma mesma *connection string* não tem problema algum.

Comment: Boa resposta, fundamentou técnicamente, e isso que importante. Realmente o que você citou é boa prática em relação a muitas entidades, separar faz um grande diferença em desempenho e organização. Parabéns ...

Answer (score 3):

Sim.

Um contexto não controla apenas os objetos carregados, mas os estados deles e todas as alterações em registros feitas dentro dele.

Carregando estes objetos em contextos separados, alterações feitas em um mesmo registro para os dois contextos podem ser perdidas, causando inconsistência de informações.

Procure usar apenas seu `DbContext<T>` para todos os `Controllers`. Não entendi exatamente a motivação para ter um contexto genérico e outro não-genérico, mas não há necessidade para tal.